# React Native QR scanner not scanning

Tags: react-native, camera, qr-code

I am trying to build a QR scanner for android in react native. I have the following code but it wont scan anything. What do I need in the code in order for it to work?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import BarcodeScanner from 'react-native-barcodescanner';

export default class test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      torchMode: 'off',
      cameraType: 'back',
    };
  }

  barcodeReceived(e) {
    console.log('Barcode: ' + e.data);
    console.log('Type: ' + e.type);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <BarcodeScanner
        onBarCodeRead={this.barcodeReceived}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        torchMode={this.state.torchMode}
        cameraType={this.state.cameraType}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```

[How it looks on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UfQz.png)

Comment: Inside your constructor add `this.barcodeReceived = this.barcodeReceived.bind(this)`, or change your function declaration to use arrow functions like so: `barcodeReceived = (e) => {}`. This is related to the context of `this` within React. Without binding or using arrow functions for lexical scoping, `this` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

use so that you can bin the Function

```
onBarCodeRead={this.barcodeReceived.bind(this)}
```

May be this can help you !!